# When writing JDBC connection pool, what is the difference of using Driver or DataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc

When I am writing connection pool to connect to database, I am always confused about the difference of using a Driver-based connection or a DataSource-based connection. It seems both of them can get the things done, but I am not sure of their difference. Can anyone tell me about it, or give me some kind of links?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataSource` and `Driver` are not comparable - `DataSource` and `DriverManager` are.

`Driver` is the basic construct of JDBC, and isn't going anywhere. The JDBC driver implementation provides this.

`DriverManager` is old, inflexible and [unofficially deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The `DataSource` interface, new in the JDBC 2.0 API, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a `DataSource` object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source.

So your primary interface to interact with for your pool is `DataSource`, not `DriverManager`. The `Driver` class will still be used, however.

Incidentally, why are you writing your own connection pool?  There are (at least) two high quality open-source implementations out there already (DBCP and C3P0).

Comment: my comp have some old code which I cannot alter and have its own connection pool. Thanks.

Comment: Will the connection using datasource faster than the connection using drivermanager?

Comment: @gunbuster363: No, there should be no performance difference.